# Make bootstrap container have only left margin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to make bootstrap container have margin on only one(left) side?.
I want the right side to stretch till end of screen... please help...

Comment: @MrLister yeah tried. entire container moves to right if i add margin-right 0

Comment: For future readers using Bootstrap 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778466/right-aligned-bootstrap-container-which-also-aligns-with-default-container

Answer (score 5):

From your query, what I understand is that you need the left border the container to be as is, but right border of the container to be stretched to right edge of the browser window. I am posting a fiddle below. Please check if it works for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/rhythm19/27x014oc/

Bascially, this is what you will need to add to get a right edged container.

```
@media (min-width:768px){
  .container-right {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: calc(50vw - 375px);
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px){
  .container-right {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: calc(50vw - 485px);
  }
}

@media (min-width:1200px){
  .container-right {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: calc(50vw - 585px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With Css3 you can use the calc function to find the correct width for your align right container.

Something like this should work :

```
.container-right {
  padding-left: 15px; //-> Add the default container padding on the left
  margin-left: auto; //-> Align your container to the right
  width: calc(1199px + (50% - 1199px / 2)); //-> The container width is based on the current breakpoint bootstrap container width
}
```

Then just duplicate this for every bootstrap breakpoint (575px / 767px / 991px / 1199px / 1599px)

Comment: definitely best answer

Answer (score 1):

Just change .container css properties like:

```
.container {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

If you want container don't moves to the right you must change container width 1170px to 1260px (if you used Bootstrap 3) Try this

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .container {
       width: 1260px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes because you have static container width and if you want container don't moves to the right you must up your container width. Let me I'll update answer

Answer (score 1):

First, the `.container` doesn't have margin.

Also I would start with the .container-fluid like so:

```css
.container-fluid {
  width: auto !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 25% !important;
}

.inner {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="inner">Container</div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wk0yeny5/

Comment: still container is moving to right.. (Iam using bootstrap 3.3.7)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're trying to accomplish? This answer seems to do exactly what you're asking, or you need to rephrase your question...

Comment: I want the container(one with margin-right 0) to align with the normal container... In the jsfiddle link in my above comment the container is moved to right

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The Bootstrap fluid container looks great on small screen, or inside CodePen where the code window is taking up the gutter on the left, but once you go full screen, the lack of a left margin is quite ugly.

Luckily Bootstrap has a built in way of dealing with this.

Just use col-xx-offset-*

For example:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">...</div>
</div>
```

When your screen is small, the left gutter disappears, and you only see it when in full screen.

This article was most useful in finding that solution: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/

Answer (score 0):

Best way is create and use half container box

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .container-half {
    width: 360px;
  }
}
@media (min-width:992px) {
  .container-half {
    width: 480px;
  }
}
@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .container-half {
    width: 570px;
  }
}
```